# how to customize UITabbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

How to customize UITabBarController to have something like this:

[image]

In its normal state, it just looks like a normal UItabbar control with a more button (the area enclosed in red rectangle). When users click more button the second row is shown up like in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CRTabBarController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/crtabbarcontroller--2).  I haven't used it but it should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a custom view that is emulating a standard view.

Search online for these, as many of them are available for general use; for instance:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tab+bar

In particular, the picture you posted *looks like* "CRTabBarController":

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/crtabbarcontroller--2

Comment: thanks for the great answer, i wish i could accept both answers.